# Uploading a file using WebDav protocol from Unix

Tags: php, webdav

I need to transfer a file from my Unix machine to a Windows machine. Problem is i can transfer a file already created on my machine via ftp from unix to any machine. also i can open webdav connection create new file and save it there.

What i am unable to do is to write my code to upload my file fro my local location using webdav.

i tried using pear client but due to lack of documentation, i am still not able to achieve the task .

Here is my attempt:

```
include("/usr/share/pear/HTTP/WebDAV/Client.php");
global $filename, $logger;
    try {
     /*   $client = new HTTP_WebDAV_Client();
        $user="username";
        $pass = "pwd";
        $dir = "webdavs://".$user.":".$pass."@hostname/";
        var_dump($client->stream_open($dir."test4.txt","w",null,$path));
        $client->stream_write("HELLO WORLD! , I am great ");
        $client->stream_close();
        $client->dir_opendir($dir,array());
        var_dump($client->dirfiles);


        $req =new HTTP_Request($dir);
        $req->setBasicAuth($user, $pass);
        $req->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST);

        $result = $req->addFile('file_upload_field', $filename);
        if (PEAR::isError($result)) {
            echo $result->getMessage();
        } else {

            $response = $req->sendRequest();

            if (PEAR::isError($response)) {
                echo $response->getMessage();
            } else {
                echo $req->getResponseBody();
            }
        }*/

        $ftp_server = "hostname-ftp";
        //$ftp_server = "hostname-webdav";
        $connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
        ftp_login($connection, 'user', 'pwd);
        ftp_put($connection, $filename, $filename, FTP_BINARY);
        unlink($filename);
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $message = "There was a problem while uploading" . $filename;
        $logger->error($message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a togh call, but i figured it out. I am adding my code snippet so it may be helpful for someone. Instead of uploading the file, i converted that file into data stream and then copied that data stream to my call that writes stream on webdav server.

```
try {
        $filecsv = file_get_contents($filename);
        $client = new HTTP_WebDAV_Client_Stream();
        $user="user";
        $pass = "pass";
        $dir = "webdavs://".$user.":".$pass."@hostname/";

        $client->stream_open($dir."db_user_exports.csv","w",null,$path);
        $client->stream_write($filecsv);
        $client->stream_close();
        unlink($filename);

    } catch(Exception $e){
        $message = "There was a problem while uploading" . $filename;
        $logger->error($message);
    }
```